Ngx-Charts - how to add text inside a normalized bar chart for each normalized section
I have created a normalized horizontal bar chart using ngx-charts
Here is my sample code https://stackblitz.com/edit/swimlane-normalized-horizontal-bar-chart-wunjep?file=app%2Fdata.ts
It looks like this

But I want to add text in the middle of the bar chart for each section so it looks something like

Is there a way to do this.
Help is much appreciated :)

It does not have the support for such customization, instead go for a highly customizable library like chart.js
Chart.js Horizontal Bar Chart Docs Example

unfortunately this is for an exisiting project which had used ngx chart everywhere. rewritin everything seems impossible at this point :( .  if it is possible to add manually  nodes that is going somewhere but i have no idea how to do it

@binga58  create using chart.js only this one chart, or inform the same that its not customizable

@binga58 For the long run chart.js is the best, its highly extensible and have a vast community for any kind of customization, you can also look at plot.ly or d3 also!
